# Windows 2008R2 RODC

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rodc

Quick and easy one for the return after Easter;)

I upgraded a clients domain a few months ago from a 2003DC to a 2008R2 Domain. All went OK, few issues we solved along the way but all good now. During the upgrade procedure I completed the necessary adprep /domainprep and /forestprep commands and never bothered withthe /RODC commands because the client had no need for this...so guess what? Yep, a few months alter and they open up a new small office and want to bung in a server down there.

So, my question is, is it OK to run the adprep /rodc commands now on the new 2008R2 DC to ensure the RODC server deploys successfully? The one and only 2003DC was successfully decommisioned some time ago and is gone forever.

Any asistance is greatly appreciated as usual ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I did the same thing.  Running the /rodcprep command is the last step.  Here is the technet article:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731243(v=ws.10).aspx

The RODCs we have work perfectly, and significantly reduced logon time from over 5 mins to under 30 seconds at a remote site serviced by a single T1 line.

Comment: Cheers for that, I just wanted to make sure it was all good to run the command now, after the fact ;)